# How to prevent the popup window closing before contact form 7 message is being displayed?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a popup window in my code. The popup window uses a contact form 7 plugin to submit values to the server. My problem is that when clicking the submit button, the popup window closes and the message "Your message has been send successfully" cannot be seen. On clicking the popup window again ,the message can only be viewed again. I wanted to display message before the popup window closes. How can I do this ?

Comment: Which jQuery are you use for pop up ?

Comment: i am using the code below for popup window. Inside that popup window i have written a contact form 7 plugin.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/jquery.popup.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     $(".js__p_start, .js__p_another_start").simplePopup();
   });
    </script>

Comment: Please see my below answer and let know if any query.

Answer (score 0):

I think popup close because contact form 7 submit button submit the form. Please remove your pop code. Please use this plugin for pop and contact form 7 plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/

First install above plugin and the contact form 7 (If not install). After that write below code in your page and your problem solve.

```
<a href="#contact_form_pop" class="fancybox">Contact Us</a>

<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
    <div id="contact_form_pop">
        [contact-form 1 "Contact form 1"]
    </div>
</div>
```